# Download leaflet map from a shiny app hosted on shiny.io

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a shiny app that displays a map from the leaflet package.
I am interested in saving the map from the shiny app as either a PNG file or HTML file. I have managed to save it as PNG file when running locally and opening the shiny app on the browser with the code below :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library( mapview)


ui <- fluidPage(
      leafletOutput(outputId = "eiffelmap")
       , downloadButton(outputId = "savemap")
       )

server <- function(input, output, server){




   name <- 'EIFFEL TOWER'
   longitude <- 2.2945
   latitude <- 48.8583
   location <- data.frame(name,longitude,latitude)

   icon.pop <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'thumb-tack',
                         markerColor = 'blue',
                         library = 'fa',
                         iconColor = 'black')
  map <- reactive({  
  name <- 'EIFFEL TOWER'
  longitude <- 2.2945
  latitude <- 48.8583
  location <- data.frame(name,longitude,latitude)

  icon.pop <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'thumb-tack',
                           markerColor = 'blue',
                           library = 'fa',
                           iconColor = 'black')

  leaflet(location) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                   options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
  ) %>%

  addAwesomeMarkers(~longitude, ~latitude, label = ~name, icon=icon.pop) 

})

output$eiffelmap <- renderLeaflet({

          map()

       })

output$savemap <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "eiffelmap.png",
    content = function(file){


     mapshot(
      x = map()
      , file = file
    )
  }
)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My question is why the download does not work when the app is hosted on **shiny.io** but works when opened locally on a browser? What is wrong with my code? 
Also any insight on how to save the leaflet map as an interactive HTML that can be zoomed in and out?
Any insight or help is highly welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you were asking this independently or as part of the app but if you want to save the map as an interactive HTML just run this part of your code and select the Export option in the Viewer pane and then Save as Web Page...

```
library(leaflet)
name <- 'EIFFEL TOWER'
longitude <- 2.2945
latitude <- 48.8583
location <- data.frame(name,longitude,latitude)

icon.pop <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'thumb-tack',
                         markerColor = 'blue',
                         library = 'fa',
                         iconColor = 'black')

leaflet(location) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                   options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
  ) %>%

  addAwesomeMarkers(~longitude, ~latitude, label = ~name, icon=icon.pop)
```

[image]

**Update:**

Please try this (using `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()`)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput(outputId = "eiffelmap")
  , downloadButton(outputId = "savemap")
)

server <- function(input, output, server){




  name <- 'EIFFEL TOWER'
  longitude <- 2.2945
  latitude <- 48.8583
  location <- data.frame(name,longitude,latitude)

  icon.pop <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'thumb-tack',
                           markerColor = 'blue',
                           library = 'fa',
                           iconColor = 'black')
  map <- reactive({  
    name <- 'EIFFEL TOWER'
    longitude <- 2.2945
    latitude <- 48.8583
    location <- data.frame(name,longitude,latitude)

    icon.pop <- awesomeIcons(icon = 'thumb-tack',
                             markerColor = 'blue',
                             library = 'fa',
                             iconColor = 'black')

    leaflet(location) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%

      addAwesomeMarkers(~longitude, ~latitude, label = ~name, icon=icon.pop) 

  })

  output$eiffelmap <- renderLeaflet({

    map()

  })

  output$savemap <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "eiffelmap.html",
    content = function(file){


      saveWidget(
        widget = map()
        , file = file
      )
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am asking for the download when it is done from a shiny app that is hosted on shiny.io .  The option you have mentioned I am well aware. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that part of the question then.

Comment: Thany you very much it works now with html widget option.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: would you have an insight on how to go about this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260164/downloading-wordcloud2-output-as-png-jpg-on-shiny/54287988#54287988